# can't export routes in express with ES6

Tags: javascript, express, es6-modules, express-router

I was writing the backend for my project. I have noticed that it was getting really messy and was repeating a lot of code over and over again. I decided to re-write everything and use classes. I also took the decision to use ES6 modules for imports.
The first bump I have ran into is that I can't seem to get my routes working.

```
import express from 'express';
export const router = express.Router();

router.post('/test', async (req, res) => {
   'test'
});
```

Importing it into server.js

```
import { router } from './routes/user.route'
server.use(router)
```

The error I get

```
Cannot find module
```

Comment: Please post the full error. This is most likely a path issue, so your directory structure wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/cFJM6Yp

Comment: Looks fine to me; maybe a space at the end of the filename or something? Any weird characters in the obscured path?

Comment: Renamed everything and tried again, still not working... I thought I did something wrong whilst exporting but really can't think of anything... been trying to get it to work for 2 hours before posting the question. xD

Comment: The correct ESM specifier would be `"./routes/user.route.js"`

Comment: Omg. Yes I just changed it as you posted that reply... can't believe I missed this....

Answer (score 1):

ES modules require literal specifiers (there is no magic resolution for extensionless names like in CJS).

In your original import statement, the specifier points to a module that doesn't exist (there is no file named `user.route` — its name is `user.route.js`):

```js
import { router } from './routes/user.route'
```

Instead, you must provide the full path (including the extension):

```js
import { router } from './routes/user.route.js'
```

See more at [Mandatory file extensions - Modules: ECMAScript modules | Node.js Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#mandatory-file-extensions)

Answer (score 0):

Try to import with a fully qualified name with extension.

```
import { router } from './routes/user.route.js'
```

Comment: Hi, please add additional details, or delete your answer. Your content is identical  to previous answer