# Updating imports and exports from CommonJS to ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I was using CommonJS but in order to use `fetch` I added `"type": "module"` to my `package.json` file. In my `index.js` file I previously had

```
const genres = require('./routes/genres');
```

and in `'./routes/genres'` I had

```
module.exports = router;
```

This worked fine but upon using

```
import genres from './routes/genres';
```

I keep getting `Cannot find module '<rest of path>/routes/genres' imported from <rest of path>/index.js Did you mean to import ../routes/genres.js?`

I also tried changing

```
module.exports = router;
```

to

```
export { router as genres };
```

or

```
export const genres = router;
```

but am still having this issue. Is there something I am missing about what is required for exporting? Finally I also just made sure that `genres.js` only uses `import` where it previously used `require`

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73309579/438273)

Comment: a) you'll want to specify the file extension b) `import genres from …` is a default import, so you'll also need to provide a default export. Or change to `import { genres } from …`.

Answer (score 0):

Import the file like this-

```
import genres from './routes/genres.js'
```

You need to include '.js' when you are using ES6 module import/export in node.

Also export the router as default-

```
export default router;
```